# Mono The task has not finished yet

Tags: c#, mono, task-parallel-library, monodevelop, async-await

Using Task, await or Task.WhenAll always return System.InvalidOperationException The task has not finished yet

I tested the same application in Windows and all runs ok.

Another problem I found is "cannot return void" when I used:

```
Task<T> exampleTask = Task<T>(()=> { code; });
```

But in Windows using .Net Framework doesn't happen

I tested it in Ubuntu 12 and OpenSuse 12 with Mono 3 installed and .Net Framework 4.5 as the target to build.

The same code in Windows runs.

The Code

```
public async Task<ViewResult> Rss()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var step1 = await client.GetStringAsync("https://github.com/mono/mono/commits/master.atom");
    var step2 = await client.GetStringAsync("https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/project/feeds/rss");
    var step3 = await client.GetStringAsync("https://orchard.codeplex.com/project/feeds/rss");

    ViewBag.MonoActivity = GetItems(step1);
    ViewBag.MVC4Activity= GetItems(step2);
    ViewBag.OrchardActivity= GetItems(step3);

    return View();
}
public IList<SyndicationItem> GetItems(String xml)
{
    var textReader = new StringReader(xml);
    var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader);
    var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlReader);
    return feed == null ? null : new List<SyndicationItem>(feed.Items);
}
```

The Stack Trace

```
System.InvalidOperationException
The task has not finished yet

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.
Exception stack trace:
```

> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000b] in
>   /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.0.4/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:62
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00021]
>   in
>   /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.0.4/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs:57 at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.lambda_method
>   (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task)  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute
>   (System.IAsyncResult)  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker/<>c_*DisplayClass21.b*_20
>   (System.IAsyncResult)  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper/WrappedAsyncResult`1.End
>   () <0x00103> at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End
>   (System.IAsyncResult,object) <0x00073> at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod
>   (System.IAsyncResult)  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker/<>c_*DisplayClass19/<>c*_DisplayClass1b.b_*15
>   ()  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker/<>c*_DisplayClass31.b__2b
>   ()

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Also, what's your actual code? And are you sure about that error message - maybe it actually says the task has not *started*?

Comment: I edited it so please, remove the down vote. You have the code and the stacktrace

Comment: Looks like a bug in Mono's `await` support. Have you asked them?

Comment: No I hope them read this, I will alert them

Comment: Mono is improving at a very fast space, I would even consider 3.0.4 to be old, you should test with Mono 3.0.11

Comment: The exception looks like Mono bug. Could you fill a bug report with full test case ?
The second issue looks good to me but it depends on what your "code" actually is. It may be a bug or just missing method overload

Comment: @knocte In few hours a will install 3.0.11 and test it, but I searched in mono bugs and I don't read any similar.

Comment: @MarekSafar if the 3.0.11 doesn't go I will create the bug with the code. But is very basic code

Comment: Definely is a bug. I installed 3.0.12 and obtained the same results

Comment: You can see the bug in this link https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12440